Which outdoor antenna can I use for mr400 TP-Link router?
Due to lack of other options, I was forced to use a 4G router. Currently I am using the MR400. Because the router is located in a building, we note that it receives little data. A ping, for example, also takes an immensely long time. To solve this, I am looking for an external outdoor antenna to connect to this. Do you have experience with certain antennas? For example, the following antenna works on this device: https://nedis.be/nl-be/product/beeld-en-geluid/antennes/5g-4g-3g/550725077/5g-4g-3g-antenne-5g-binnen-buiten-698-5000-mhz-versterking-6-db-2-50-m-wit
Other recommendations are always welcome as well. Because there is also some space between the router and the device that needs to receive the network, we still want enough coverage.
Thanks in advance for your help!
I don't know enough about antenna's in combination with 4G routers. So I hope someone can give some recommendations.

Depends on many factors such as building construction, blackspots, wifi coverage etc.
If you're not getting good connection due to metal or stone construction then adding an antenna isn't going to do much. You will be better to get a network switch and cable to an AP instead. Something like an Aruba:
https://www.comms-express.com/products/aruba-ap22-instant-on-access-point/
Like I said, it all depends on location and number of users.

Hi thanks for your answer but it is not possible to work with a cable because I couldn't place any modem on that location. Otherwise I would make my own stable network. Do you have other recommendations?

You could try a powerline adaptor or a wifi booster?

That's a much bigger question than you think.  Practical advice first then some background so you can decide if you want to take it:
The line connecting an antenna at 2.4GHz attenuates up to 8dB of signal per meter.  It's going to be almost impossible to find an omnidirectional antenna that you can mount outdoors with enough gain to offset the signal loss from the cable.  Antennas on Amazon claiming more than 3-6 dB of gain are almost certainly lying to you with very rare exceptions.  The antennas already on the device are likely as good as almost all antennas you would find on Amazon if you don't have the background for identifying antenna characteristics and evaluating seller claims.
Your better move is to use the hole you were going to have to punch in the wall for the antenna line and run a network cable to connect to a PoE powered externally rated WiFi router mounted where you were going to mount the external antenna.  As an LTE router with no network connection, the network cable through the wall would only be for power, but that's almost always much easier than running a power cable to the device.
If you can't put a router outdoors, I'm not sure where you intended to mount the antenna.
If that won't work for you, there are two cases where using an external antenna might make sense:

You may actually have plenty of signal but the wall is blocking it (metal siding for example). If so, even with a potentially extreme drop in signal, you just need to get the antenna outdoors.  In that case use the shortest antenna line that will work (those look like they're probably RP-SMA connectors) with a female to male extension cable and just reuse the antenna you already have.
You only have one device outdoors you need to connect to and it's location is fixed so you can use a directional antenna.  Directional antennas get more range in one direction by sacrificing it in every other direction. A Yagi or possibly panel antenna on the router and the device pointing at each other might do the trick, but it's a try it and see exercise with consumer grade equipment.

A few other thoughts for you.  2.4GHz WiFi has better range than 5GHz.  With two antennas, it's probably configured as one antenna for 2.4GHz and one for 5GHz, but there are a lot of other ways it could be configured that would make life more difficult for you.  If you try to move the antennas, don't bother with the 5GHz antenna (assuming that's how it's configured) and hopefully the connections are labeled as one 5GHz, one 2.4GHz.  it might be one RX and one TX antenna instead,for example, with each covering both bands and you'd need to extend both through the wall.
The specs on the MR400 say receive sensitivity peaks at -76 for 2.4GHz.  With the RX sensitivity specification you're looking at the weakest signal the device claims to reliably receive, so lower is better.  I usually work with Bluetooth in 2.4GHz, so I'm not sure what the best WiFi routers are doing these days, but the worst Bluetooth chipsets do -85 to -87 and under the right circumstances some do -105.  dB  is logarithmic, so every -3 dB difference means the device can detect a signal half as strong, so a 10 or 20 dB signal difference is huge.  If you replace the router it wouldn't hurt to look for one with better specs.
Figure out how to use an external router instead and you'll avoid a lot of effort for something that may or may not work anyway.
